# Performance improvement in JPQL Query for update same table

Tags: java, database, jpa, ejb, jpql

I want to update a table using jpql. Table structure and condition and query is below.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
ASSIGNMENT | BUSINESS_AREA | DC_CURRENCY | DC_AMOUNT | STATUS
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

In above table structure I want to update all the rows status as completed
where sum of DC_AMOUNT is ZERO and DC_CURRENCY is same for all rows , and ASSIGNMENT is also same

My approach

1. Get all assignment number by query in java layer
2. Update status to completed for all assignment number which I got in previous result set

Query to get all assignment number satisfying condition

```
SELECT 
    q.assignment 
FROM 
    OnAccoutEntity q, OnAccoutEntity r 
WHERE 
    q.assignment = r.assignmet 
    AND q.dcCurrency = r.dcCurrency 
    AND q.businessArea = r.businessArea 
GROUP BY 
    q.assignmnt 
HAVING 
    SUM(q.dcAmount) = 0

UPDATE OnAccoutEntity p
SET p.status = 'COMPETED'
WHERE p.assignment IN ("Result of previous query' )
```

If I use single query to update it is giving exception.

> java.sql.SQLException: You cant specify target 'ONACCCOUNT' for update in form clause.

Please suggest a better approach as this is time consuming.

Comment: Use the first query as a subquery of the second one: `where p.assignment in (select q.assignment ...)`?

Comment: It dosent work becaue it gives error "Cant specify target table for Update"
Please write query I may be doing that wrong

Comment: When something doesn't work and you want to know why, edit your question with the relevant code and the exact and complete stack trace.

Comment: I have edited question , Please Iet me know how can I solve this

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

It should do with an [EXISTS](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_exists),

```
UPDATE
   OnAccoutEntity o
SET
   o.status = 'COMPLETED'
WHERE
   EXISTS (SELECT
              q.assignment
           FROM
              OnAccoutEntity q
           WHERE
              o.assignment = q.assignment
           AND
              q.dcCurrency = o.dcCurrency
           AND
              q.businessArea = r.businessArea
           GROUP BY
              q.assignment
           HAVING SUM(q.dcAmount) = 0)
```

Comment: This is giving Exception ::: java.sql.SQLException: You cant specify target 'ONACCCOUNT' for update in form clause